warning message after install Intervention Image Package for Laravel

Hello, I deiced to write some code that compress the image size before uploaded to the app, than i hear about Intervention Image Package and i install it V3 after that their is a some steps like install (ImageMagick ) and (imagick) i do it all.


its show message:

PHP Warning:  Version warning: Imagick was compiled against ImageMagick version 1808 but version 1809 is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave surprisingly in Unknown on line 0

the message in the terminal

when i run the server and when i upload the image that error show?
the error after uploaded
my code in controller
php info


solve my problem please

